# UnboundLocalError at / local variable 'context' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-views

Getting this error with views.py in my Django app -
UnboundLocalError at /
local variable 'context' referenced before assignment.

Here is a snippet of the code that is not working:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

def store(request):
products = Product.objects.all()
context: {'products':products}
return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)
```

Comment: `context` isn't defined anywhere before you reference it, exactly as the error message states. I believe you made a simple typo, `context: {'products':products}` -> `context = {'products':products}` otherwise what you have is a variable *type annotation* not an assignment statement

Comment: It was the typo, thanks for pointing it out. Works great now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

def store(request):
products = Product.objects.all()
context = {'products':products} #I have changed : to =
return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you. My bad, that works perfectly now.